# Images Not rendering with Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a simple web app containing main js file and Jade file representing main page. JS file looks like this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = new express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('character', {
        exp : 0,
        requiredExp : 0,
        coins : 0,
        frames : [
            'bronze_frame',
            'silver_frame',
            'golden_frame',
            'jade_frame',
            'conduit_frame',
            'tempest_frame'
        ],
        badges : [
            'night_edge_badge',
            'arcanum_badge'
        ]
    });
});

app.listen(25555);
```

And the Jade file like this:

```html
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        //link(href="./css/character.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")
    body
        div
            img(src="./assets/wizard.png")
            progress(value=exp, max=requiredExp)
        div
            img(src="./assets/coin.png")
            p= coins
        div.showcase
            for frame in frames
                img(src='/assets/#{frame}.png')
        div.showcase
            for badge in badges
                image(src='/assets/#{badge}.png')
```

And when I run JS file and try to connect to it, I get this:

[image]

The jade file is in "view" folder, "assets" folder is also in "view" folder.
So why images isn't drawn? I need an explanation and, if possible, solution of the issue.

Comment: I think you have to tell Express to use the static middleware to serve your static assets: `app.use(express.static('public'));` where public is your directory containg your assets: http://expressjs.com/fr/starter/static-files.html

Comment: use the full path - `path.join(__dirname, '<YOUR_PATH>')`

Comment: Plus, check the paths. Sometimes you use `./assets`, others `/assets`

Comment: @cl3m yeah, I was trying to figure out how the path should look like. So, for example, if the ones with `./assets` had shown up, I'd understand that the other ones are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell Express to use the `static` middleware to serve your static content (css, js, jpg...):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = new express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

More info in the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/fr/starter/static-files.html).

Also, make sure that your assets paths are consistent: is it `./assets` or `/assets` ?

```
img(src="./assets/coin.png")
div.showcase
    for frame in frames
        img(src='/assets/#{frame}.png')
```